# How to optimize Cypher Query planner or force the planner to use different index for first index scan

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
match (s:Subscriber {field_9 : 'female'})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(:SubscriberList {id: 4})
return count(s).
```

This is a simple query with one relation and 2 filters. because Subscriber is big up to 7m nodes I want to use field_9 as a first NodeIndexSeek, because SubscriberList label only contains 15 nodes. currently, profile looks like

[image]

if I change the query and force to use indexs results will be:

```
match (s:Subscriber {field_9 : 'female'})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(:SubscriberList {id: 4}) 
using index s:Subscriber(field_9) 
return count(s)
```

[image]

More optimised query could be done with a subquery:

```
match (s:Subscriber { field_9: 'female' })-[:BELONGS_TO]-(sl:SubscriberList) 
with  count(s) as ss, sl.id as slId where slId = 4 
return ss, slId
```

[image]

but my goal is to use the first query and try to force the planner to use field_9 as a first NodeIndexSeek. Is there any idea how to achieve this?

first query:

```
match (s:Subscriber {field_9 : 'female'})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(:SubscriberList {id: 4}) 
return count(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* work:

```
MATCH (s:Subscriber {field_9: 'female'})-[:BELONGS_TO]->(sl:SubscriberList {id: 4}) 
USING INDEX s:Subscriber(field_9) 
USING SCAN sl:SubscriberList 
RETURN COUNT(s)
```

That [USING SCAN](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/using/#query-using-scan-hint) hint tells Cypher to use scanning to find the desired `sl` nodes rather than the associated index. However, since the `s` node is found via indexing, *hopefully* the planner will be smart enough to generate a plan that follows the `BELONGS_TO` relationship to find the related `SubscriberList`s (instead of actually scanning all `SubscriberList` nodes).

You should profile this query and compare the total number of DB hits with your other queries to find the one that works best.